# Warming Lambda via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have some Lambda functions that are utilized with API Gateway.  I'm attempting to find a good warming strategy to help minimize cold starts.  Currently, I'm invoking these functions from another lambda every 2 minutes.  I can see in logs that this is correctly invoking the functions.

Consistently however, if I wait 15 or 30 minutes and hit the API, it appears to be a cold start (1-3s response time), typical response is around 100ms +- 50ms.

I understand that this warming method would warm for single concurrency and if I wanted to better effectively warm these at higher concurrency I would need to invoke them as such.  But this is not an active api, just my own invokes/requests so concurrency issues shouldn't be coming in to play.

My question is that when using API Gateway, does invoking your lambdas outside of API Gateway actually "warm" them? It just doesn't seem to be in practice or perhaps 2 minute increments isn't enough? Would I be better actually hitting the endpoints themselves vs. invoking the lambdas?

Appreciate any suggestions, just seems that warming every 2 minutes using invoke, isn't really doing anything.

Comment: Do you know if the invocation that appears to be a cold start is *actually* a cold start? To test if a given invocation in actually reusing a warmed Lambda container, you could have the Lambda store some value (e.g. the Lambda request ID) outside of the event handler, in the global context. Print that out in your event handler to see if it was set by a previous, warming Lambda.

Comment: @jarmon thank you, i don't actually, i'll try that and comment back

Comment: @jarmon so I stored the request id globally and could see that it didn't change at first, made about 15 requests and the stored id remained the same.  However, I let it go for about an hour and the stored id changed.  During this time, I did still have it being "warmed up" ever 2 minutes and I can see it hit in the logs in that interval, so it did appear to be a cold start after a period of time.

Comment: I'm not generally a big fan of warming tbh because you don't have enough information about how the Lambda service is operating internally, plus you're paying for the wasted invocations. Static warming strategies (e.g. invoke Lambda every N minutes) are probably sub-optimal too as they don't adapt to what the underlying service may be doing. There are a number of open source packages (e.g. serverless-plugin-warmup) that might be worth looking at to see if they are effective, to see what what strategies they employ, and to bounce any problems off the authors.

Comment: @jarmod yeah i'm using that same plugin, it works.. but your probably right, maybe just not very effective in real world.